# Will GCC support C++ AMP

Tags: c++, c++-amp

Does anyone know if there are any plans to develop support in g++ (GCC) for the new [C++ AMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137%28VS.110%29.aspx) standard which was [released](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/article/414567/microsoft_opens_c_extension_other_compilers) recently by Microsoft as an [open specification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/02/03/c-amp-open-spec-published.aspx)? I see someone is [already asking about Intel support in their forums](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=102867&o=a&s=lr). But I haven't seen anything for GCC.

Comment: It doesn't look like a *standard* to me - it also seems to be Windows-only ?

Comment: C++ AMP is an open standard created at Microsoft. Yes, it is currently windows only, but that's the whole point of the question...

Comment: According to the blog on MSDN it's an "open specification" and it's based on DirectX.

Comment: Perhaps their version uses DirectX, but I think I remember reading that they want it to be able to be used with other back-ends, like OpenCL.

Comment: Well as the old saw goes: "When you dine with the devil, take a long spoon".

Comment: I think it would be great to see an OpenCL based implementation in an open source compiler like clang or gcc. I haven't seen anyone discussing doing it yet though.

Comment: If you want a definitive answer, you should ask on the gcc mailing lists.

Comment: Just an update Clang is getting AMP soon, hope to see it in gcc as well =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the standard becomes a true ISO standard then it's likely in the future but virtually anything licensed under the MS-PL is always addressed with caution by the FSF (large parts of Mono for instance). Richard Stallman is very against using Microsoft open code and he still has many ties, although mostly political, to GCC so I doubt that the current spec of AMP will be supported. Any open source support is more likely to come from the Clang project. Their BSD style license is much more permissive and the community around it is more open to collaboration with commercial entities.

Update: I mistyped EFF (Electronic Frontier Foundation), intending to write FSF (Free Software Foundation). Thank you [Max Laybbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10593/max-lybbert) for pointing that out.

Comment: I know it's late, but I've got to nitpick:  the FSF (Free Software Foundation) is the organization behind GCC, not the EFF (Electronic Frontier Foundation, which is usually behind filing lawsuits).  They are two separate organizations with no formal connection to each other.

Comment: You're right, sorry I got my acronyms mixed up. What's worse is I work for the government, they are all about acronyms around here.

Comment: As it's a specification, not source code, MS-PL doesn't apply. Microsoft has copyright on the document, though with some relevant grants, and gives patent rights under their "Community Promise": http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/en/us/programs/community-promise/default.aspx  So it's not really anything Stallman can sanely argue against: not that that's ever stopped him.

Comment: Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265136(v=vs.110).aspx) every example of code utilizing AMP has an include to amp.h so there is code that comes with the spec. It would need code since the spec extends the C++ language, and so far as I know here aren't any alternative header files implementing that spec so Thr ms-pl is still a "problem".

Comment: @flipchart There have been at least two projects to investigate implementing C++ AMP on top of LLVM and OpenCL; http://gpuscience.com/news/intel-shevlin-park-cross-platform-implementation-of-c-amp-in-clangllvm-using-opencl/ and http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM1MTQ.

Comment: @sean_m You should read the relevant material here, http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/en/us/programs/community-promise/default.aspx. My understanding is that the headers are part of the implementation not the spec.

Comment: I did read that, I was commenting on their not being a fully baked implementation so in order to use actually use the tech without implementing your own runtime library you've got to deal with the license, but it seams like Intel has come to save the day.

Comment: AMP are developing an AMP implementation:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2013/11/13/c-amp-to-target-khronos-spir-and-hsail.aspx There is also a V1.2 spec: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2013/12/12/c-amp-open-spec-v1-2-published.aspx

Answer (score 11):

The [article](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2012/02/microsoft-publishes-fancy-pants-heterogeneous-parallel-gpgpu-c-amp-specification.ars/) over at Ars says:
>

> AMP has been developed by Microsoft with input from AMD and NVIDIA.
>   Microsoft's implementation allows AMP programs to use both the main
>   CPU and Direct3D video cards (via the company's DirectCompute API),
>   though the specification should also permit OpenGL/OpenCL-based
>   implementations.
>
> Microsoft encourages other compiler developers to implement the
>   technology. The published specification includes within it an
>   irrevocable promise to not assert claims on any patents that Microsoft
>   may hold that are relevant to AMP unless the implementing party sues
>   Microsoft for patent infringement.

I can't answer the original question, which seems interesting to me, but the quote above from Ars does address some of the comments that have already been posted.

Comment: IANAL but this seems like a trojan horse to me. Firstly it sounds like it is incompatible with the GPL so GCC can't benifit. Additionally it would be hard to see this in Clang, since if they where to use it neither Apple or Google (2 major users and contributors to of Clang) would be able to enforce patents against them (but the reverse wouldn't be true). Finally I wonder how far it would trickle down, ie if use Clang with C++ AMP in it to make my own program, would I now no longer be able to sue Microsoft? So it doesn't surprise me that they are 'encouraging' compilers to use the technology.

Comment: The implementation, which is not open source (MS-PL or otherwise) is not the same as the specification. If a third party decided to implement the specification then there might be IP/parent issues if Microsoft claimed any patents on the material described in the specification. However it is harder to defend a patent that you have placed in the public domain and presumably any serious implementer would resolve those issues prior to distributing their work.